# My account lost association with user93359 and end up being asked to create a blank, new account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've used StackExchange for a couple weeks. I used my Facebook log-in for the site. I took about a week break from it and as of today, when I tried to access Worldbuilding which is my most used network, it asked me to join the community. I click yes, then went through the process thinking its some kind of normal log-in behavior.. only to find my entire worldbuilding account statitsics to be blank!

Oddly enough, as far as I can tell all my other network associations and history remained in tact. I can still find my old Worldbuilding post, which is now attributed to "user93359". Here is an example: [Aliens exist on the other side of the nearby wormhole, but we don't know wormhole exists yet. How might they be detected and communicated with?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/221501/aliens-exist-on-the-other-side-of-the-nearby-wormhole-but-we-dont-know-wormhol)

What can I do about this and how can this be fixed?

Comment: And your username "was" Beyond Disbelief, too? If so, that's really weird o_x.

Comment: Suspended for voting irregularities, apparently. Ooooo.

Answer (score 3):

Easy.

You can use the "Contact" button at the bottom of any page on the network, it leads [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/contact) to a contact-form. You'll be able to leave an explanation/request for a staff member to fix it for you by merging the accounts or re-setting the login for you. It may take a day or two, longer at weekends depending on their workload.

Logging in, personally I use the [common stack-exchange login](https://stackexchange.com/) so I can log into all the sites at once, also a password manager, there are many free and secure ones like [Lastpass](https://www.lastpass.com/), [Stickypassword](https://www.stickypassword.com/), [Dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com/) to save labour. I use Lastpass, it works fine on Android as well as PC.